# Wrong answer in a codechef c code(codechef-STATUES)

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve this question, but on codechef its showing wrong answer,link to the queston is http://www.codechef.com/problems/STATUES/  .On system ,its showing correct answer, after trying a lot, i couldnt find the bug My code is,

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[150];
    int n;
    int i;
    int sum;
    int avg;
    int count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int ans;
    int diff;
    while(n!=0)
    {

    sum=0;
    ans=0;
    count++;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        sum=sum+a[i];
    }

    avg=sum/n;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   diff=avg-a[i];
        if(diff>0)
        ans=ans+diff;
    }
    printf("Set#%d\nThe minimum number of moves is %d.\n",count,ans);
    scanf("%d",&n);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: ...and the question too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the condition in the question:

> **Output a blank line after each test case**.
>   Be careful about the case and punctuation in the above strings. Not adhering to the output format strictly will lead to the Wrong Answer verdict.

There is no blank line after your each output. Also one more `for` loop is needed to met the condition for exact output format.  Add this snippet after `while`.

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
       printf("\nSet #%d\nThe minimum number of moves is %d.\n",i,ans); 
  }
```

Another problem is

```
int a[150];
```

`a` should not exceed from `50`. Change it to

```
int a[50];
```

But I woul advice you to use [variable length array](http://docs.cray.com/books/004-2179-001/html-004-2179-001/z893434830malz.html) in this case to save memory.